# OSX accessibility: Allow Skype to control your computer

Tags: macos, skype, privacy, osx-mavericks, accessibility

This question is related to another question: ["Google Software Update would like to control this computer..." What?](https://superuser.com/questions/657015/google-software-update-would-like-to-control-this-computer-what) only I'd like to know why Skype would like access to control my computer? Is this for screen sharing perhaps? I searched Google but found no explanation of this setting.

Settings I am referring to are found under System Preferences -> Security & Privacy -> Accessibility.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Security and Privacy dialog here is a little bit deceiving in its wording. Skype is allowed to access the **Accessibility** function of the computer. Skype needs Accessibility in order to do the following in the Mac OS environment:

- VoiceOver
- Contrast adjustment/color inversion for low vision users
- Zoom content for low vision users

If you don't feel comfortable using Skype with these privileges granted to it, you may be able to uncheck the box for it in that window you screenshotted and it may still let you operate without these extra Accessibility privileges.

Comment: Would you be able to provide a link to the source of your answer?

Comment: See under section "Skype for Mac": https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA12371/what-accessibility-features-are-available-for-skype