# How to give Screen Recording permission to Skype for Business on MacOs Mojave?

Tags: macos, permissions, skype, macos-mojave, skype-for-business

I'm using Skype for Business on MacOs Mojave 10.14.6. 
When I try to do Screen Sharing, I get message that I need to give permissions to Skype.
From what I could gather, I'm supposed to select Screen Recording option in:

System Preferences -> Security and Privacy -> Privacy

However, Screen Recording option not visible in the list of on the left side. I have also activated Screen Sharing option in System Preferences -> Sharing.

Why is this option not visible in the list?

How can I give Screen Recording permission to Skype?

[image: message screenshot]

Comment: I think this question belongs on this site>>>>https://apple.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I can see a very similar question in this site: https://superuser.com/questions/699058/osx-accessibility-allow-skype-to-control-your-computer?rq=1

Comment: Screen Sharing is in System Prefs>Sharing>Screen Sharing. [I can'r help further as I I have remote management switched on here which overrides screen sharing]

Comment: Your new image says screen recording, not screen sharing. I've never seen a screen recording option in Privacy - but I don't use Skype

Comment: thank you, you are right, message is saying Recording, not Sharing. @Tetsujin, I also tried activating Screen Sharing in Sharing.  Did not help